# Receive text from the Android share menu

Tags: android, intentfilter

I can't find this problem anywhere, so it's probably something stupidly simple.

I'm trying to register my app's MainActivity to receive plain text from other apps via the share menu, but nothing I do seems to get it working. When I select text in the web browser and click the "share" icon my app is not listed as an option.

Here's the relevant part of the android manifest:

```
  <application
      android:name=".App"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
```

I also tried other actions such as `SENDTO` and `VIEW` to no avail. The problem I have is that my app simply does not appear as an option in the share menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Example](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) you forget to add data mimeType

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, it doesn't work with a mimeType either. I removed the mimeType as part of trying to track down the problem.

Comment: try those mimeType="text/*" or mimeType="plain/*"

Comment: Fantastic... now that I added it back it's suddenly working. ¬¬ I swear it is exactly the same as it was yesterday.

Comment: Seriously, that example is exactly what I started with. Oh well... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, the one in your answer.